# Numerical solution of a system of Heat (Diffusion) Equations - Continuous flow between bodies

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, heat-equation, finite-differences

I am assosiated on a research project, where we wish to simulate a physical system with a system of heat equations as the governing equations. An example in $1D$ would look something like the following:

\begin{align} 
\frac{1}{\alpha_1} \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial t} &= \frac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial x^2} + P_0(1+\cos(2\omega t)), \quad x\in [-L,0] \\\ 
\frac{1}{\alpha_2} \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial t} &= \frac{\partial^2 u_2}{\partial x^2}, \quad x\in [0,L],
\end{align}

where $\alpha_1\neq \alpha_2$, $\frac{\partial u_1(-L,t)}{\partial x} = 0 = \frac{\partial u_2(L,t)}{\partial x}$,  $u_1(x,0)=f_1(x)$ and $u_2(x,0)=f_2(x)$. Furthermore, we might assume $f_1$ and $f_2$ are constant. At the boundary between bodies, i.e. $x=0$, we assume there is a continuous flow of heat, and this is where my problem comes in.

It is easy enough to solve the heat equations seperately using standard finite difference methods, but how do I deal with this shared boundary where there is a continuous flow?
I have tried to find literature, code examples, etc., which might help me understand this but came up empty handed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try first coming up with a mathematical formulation of a "continuous flow of heat"?

Comment: @K.defaoite That is a great point. I imagined something like:
$$ \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x} = -c \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x},$$
where $c$ is a constant which depends on $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$. However, I'm not sure about this formulation.

Comment: @Gonçalo I have seen similar solutions before, so indeed that is a posibility. Two problems: 1) Heaviside is not exactly "nice", since the derivative is the Dirac delta function. 2) This was a simplified version. I'm actually working in $2$D, where the bodies are sharing an edge. This solution might still work but I'm worried that the simulation will no capture the behavior around the shared edge.

Do you believe this will still work in $2$D (with a modified $\alpha(x)$)?

Comment: @Gonçalo I will try both Heaviside and the smooth option. I was already thinking about a sigmoid function. The PDE solver that I'm using in Python, does not allow specifying boundary conditions in that way. Maybe in the end, I will be forced to make a solver myself.